# finding a value in a list just less than or equal to key

Tags: python, algorithm, search

given a sorted array i want to get the smallest element which is equal to or just less then the passed key

i already tried finding gap between every element and returning the one with least gap but that does not give the desired result as it also returns the value greater then the passed one

```
sorted_li= [25,22,15,14,12,6,4]
def find_nearest_small_value(key,sorted_li):
    gap_current, gap_global, value = 0, key, sorted_li[0]
    for i in sorted_li:
        gap_current = abs(i-key)
        if gap_global>=gap_current:
            gap_global=gap_current
            value=i
    return value
```

for example the above code with key=19 will return 22 because gap is 3 there although it should return 15 as it's less then 19 with lest gap

any help will be appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Sounds like you are using the wrong "Gap" calculation then...

Comment: This code always returns 4... Did you mean to `return value`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes u r right although that was a typo it still does not return the desired output

Comment: I'm not sure why you think you need to calculate gaps. You can return the element that is immediately less than or equal to the key while iterating

Comment: @cricket_007 yes thanks for the insight. although this won't work  if the list is not sorted already

Comment: You literally said **given a sorted array**. If you have an unsorted array, then that is a separate question

Comment: Even if it was unsorted, are you not allowed to sort it?

Comment: I think you may have phrased your question wrongly. I believe you meant to ask: given a sorted array, find the __largest__ element which is equal to or less then the passed key ?

Comment: @GaryGoh yes! that will do.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for sorted and unsorted input sequences:

```
def find_nearest_small_value(key, sorted_li):
    return max(i for i in sorted_li if i <= key)
```

it is very easily readable and a simple solution

Comment: this is O(N), compared to solutions that include sorting (which is O(NlogN))

Comment: Very true. Although it is an option. Its probably not the best option

Comment: Really? I thought O(NlogN)) could be faster in some cases here compared to O(n) or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can find the value of `N` to make `O(N) > O(NlogN)` =)

Answer (score 1):

### Naive Approach

Traverse through every element in the given sorted list, and return the element when the condition is fulfilled. The worse case complexity is `O(n)`.

```
def find_nearest_small_value(key, sorted_li):
    for i in sorted_li:
        if i <= key:
            return i
    return None
```

### Effficient Approach: Binary Search

Cut the search space in half each time we compare, and thus making the algorithm more efficient. The complexity is `O(log n)`.

```
def find_nearest_small_value(key, sorted_li):
    element = None
    start = 0
    end = len(sorted_li)
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if mid >= len(sorted_li):  # out of bounds
            break
        if sorted_li[mid] <= key:
            element = sorted_li[mid]
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return element
```

Comment: yes this works.Although i should have mentioned the possibility of unsorted list

Comment: your `for` loop will make exactly 1 (one) iteration in the successful case, or pointlessly loop until the end if all values are greater than `key`.

Comment: Yes, I also assumed that the given sorted list is sorted in descending order (largest to smallest). You can alway use the `sorted(list, reverse=True)` on the list first if the list is unsorted. However, that will increase the time complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Why would anyone need a loop for that?? Return the first element as the smallest, if it's less than the `key` or `None` otherwise:

```
def find_nearest_small_value( key, sorted_list ) :
    return sorted_list[0] if sorted_list[0] <= key else None
```

---

Answering the question below:

```
>>> def find_nearest_small_value( key, sorted_list ) :
...     return sorted_list[0] if sorted_list[0] <= key else None
... 
>>> find_nearest_small_value( 31, [22,25,28,39] )
22
```

Comment: how are u suppose to check for every element without checking all of them

Comment: @abhay in the sorted array the smallest element is the first, why do I need to check all of them?

Comment: if li = [22,25,28,39] and i'm giving key=31 it will return 22 although desired output is 28

Comment: perhaps i should ask my question as return the LARGEST element that is less than or equal to the given key in a list

Comment: @abhay see the edit, everything works as it's supposed to.